# Get single record from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table1:

```
Name      address    city     id
--------------------------------
abc       123        def      1
def       145        dsa      2
```

Table2:

```
Job        Description     id
-----------------------------------
work1      empl            1
work2      waiter          1
work3      empl            1
work3      electrician     1
work3      plumber         1
job1       empl4           2
job5       empl5           2
job3       empl 2          2
```

I have these 2 tables.

- Table 1 stores persons details like "name, address,city, Id"
- Table 2 stores persons job details like "job, description, Id".

Here in table 2, the persons job details may contains many records with same id. But what I need is to fetch a records from Table 1 "name, address,city" using the id of table 2 only if job details records is greater than 5.

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How about you try to do this for yourself before coming here? We're not here to write code for you I'm afraid.

Comment: only if job details records is greater than 5? Do you mean has more than 5 distinct jobs?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2
    WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id
) > 5
```

Comment: do you really think this will not give syntax error

Comment: yes i tested it before posting.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine with this query

Comment: No problem. select the tick marking the answer correct for other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
select * 
from Table1 as a
where a.id in
    (select distinct b.id 
        from Table2 as b
        group by b.id
        having count(id)>5)
```

First, in the inner select, you get the id's that have more than 5 rows, then you select the rows from table 1 that match that condition

Comment: Thanks..! This is what I expected

Comment: @Arun so then upvote and accept the answer